# IIS Arr not passing windows credentials on the same server

Tags: windows-authentication, arr

I have a self-hosted owin web api service on a test environment, and to give it a better name I use a domain alias, and ARR.

My web api runs on port 8888, and uses Windows Authentication. I have configured my arr to run under `testserver:80` with anonymous authentication. I want to deploy a service on the box that will pool the webapi for data. When I try to visit `testserver` from my web browser on my desktop it works fine. However, when I remote into that box and try to hit `testserver` it prompts me for credentials. Even if I type them correctly it still will issue me a 401. If I go to `localhost:8888` the site will work.

Since, I'd prefer to use the pretty name for the server in my service how do I correct this issue. How do I get it to pass credentials on the same box through ARR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have have an issue with LSA loopback checking.

You get the 401 because ARR forwards your Windows Authentication to localhost, which is not allowed (default setting).

Try to disable LSA loopback checking (restart most probably required). If that works you can limit the disabling of loopback checking to specific websites (to prevent security holes).

See [You receive error 401.1 when you browse a Web site that uses Integrated Authentication and is hosted on IIS 5.1 or a later version](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861) for more information on the LSA loopback check and how to disable it completely or only for specific hostnames.